# Parse a string with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I keep product options as string in DB, and I need to parse it (string to array).

String is:

{option_name:option_id{variant_id:variant_name}}

How can I parse it with using PHP?

Comment: It looks like a JSON string. Why not just use json_decode()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`?

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Instead of converting your product to the string you have above, take the product (I'm assuming it's an array) and then serialize it `serialize($myproductarray)`. That turns it into a portable string. When you need the info from the database, get the string, and `unserialize($myproductstring)` to get it back into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't detail the field formats so here's a guestimate that you can tweak:

```
preg_match('/^{(\w+):(\d+){(\d+):(\w+)}}$/', '{an_option_name:123{456:a_variant_name}}', $matches);

$option_name  = $matches[1];
$option_id    = $matches[2];
$variant_id   = $matches[3];
$variant_name = $matches[4];
```